# How to get available contexts in iOS application

Tags: ios, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to get the available contexts in hybrid iOS app. However, when I do

```
Set<String> text =  ((IOSDriver) driver).getContextHandles();
  System.out.println(text);
```

I get below error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to io.appium.java_client.IOSDriver
```

When I try to create AppiumDriver with:

```
driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

It is not allowing to create AppiumDriver. How to get available contexts in iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a real device you need to run ios-webkit-debug-proxy so inside your driver set the capability called `webkitDebugProxyPor`" to the port you want, and also activate the capability called `startIWDP`.

Make sure you have installed ios-webkit-debug-proxy, which is easily installed using `brew install ios-webkit-debug-proxy`

Once you have everything up and running you should be able to see the web context.

Answer (score 0):

Declare driver as type AppiumDriver. 
Use this a reference for IOSDriver. Then it would work. At the moment, it seems driver variable is of type of remotewebdriver.

So following code will work

```
AppiumDriver driver;

driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

Set<String> text =  ((IOSDriver) driver).getContextHandles();
  System.out.println(text);
```

AppiumDriver is abstract driver which you can use as base type reference to instantiated driver whether IOS or Andriod

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code you suggested. However, it still gave me the same error. I then changed method driver.getContextHandles(); to driver.getContext(); Further it returned me only NATIVE_APP context, where there is WebView present in app. Any idea why the second method worked and why it is not returning me WEBVIEW .

Comment: Which version of appium java client you using?

Comment: I am using Java Client 2.1.0   appium version 1.4.8 and iPad 8.1.3.

Comment: Give it a try with capability of autoWebview as true

Comment: I am setting autoWebview true before initializing  the driver. However it gives me error similar to : "Unable to switch to webview" , since there is no webview on first screen of my app,

Comment: may be silly question? is your application hybrid application ?

Comment: Hi, I could get all the available contexts in my iOS Hybrid App. I managed to resolve the problem  with ios-debug-webkit-proxy. Now I am getting [NATIVE_APP,WEBVIEW_21,WEBVIEW_22] the elements I am trying to locate are in WEBVIEW_22. context also successfully getting switched to WEBVIEW_22. However, elements are still not getting located. (This can be seperate SO question, but it would be helpful if you can provide some solution here) :)